# Parallel Threading in Multi-Language Software?

Tags: java, c#, c++, c, multithreading

I'm developing a software that contain many modules/Daemon running in parallel manner, what i'm looking for is how to implement that, i cannot use Thread because some of those modules/Daemon are perhaps implemented in other languages (C,java,C#...).

For example I'm using C for Hooking Messages exchanged between Windows kernel and top level applications, Java/C# to use some free library to simply parse XML(for example) or to accept and execute commands over the network..this can be done by C Language but just to improve productivity...
Finally for GUI I'm using [Ultimate++](http://ultimatepp.org/) (c++) that is like the main process that call and monitor(activate/deactivate/get state) of all other modules/Daemon through an interface.

I admit that the development of each module/Daemon in a separate language greatly facilitates maintenance, but especially I am obliged to do that..
What is the best practice way to do that ?

All helps will be appreciated.

Comment: In all fairness, C++ could easily replace C for almost all tasks, and certainly in Win32. Parsing XML is indeed easier in C# than in C, but again C++ is a good candidate. I.e. you could write the whole thing in just C++. Some people are overlooking that C++ is far more than "C with classes"

Comment: 'i cannot use Thread because some of those modules/Daemon are perhaps implemented in other languages (C,java,C#...)'??  A thread is a OS unit of execution.  No thread, no execution.  If you cannot call something from a thread, you cannot call it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Message passing  is probably a good option.  On UNIX pipes and sockets would be a standard way to accomplish that.  (Windows has similar concepts.)  In fact this even simplifies concurrency because you don't share any memory.

Comment: I think there are MPI C libraries available for most OS's? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface